# Region in Brazil and HTTP/2 Heroku

Tags: heroku, http2

Does anyone know if Heroku is going to launch a new region in Brazil? I really like the service, but I believe that hosting my site in other regions compromises a little the performance of my applications.

Another question is about HTTP/2. It's time to upgrade to HTTP / 2, right? Does anyone know when they think about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku do not support HTTP/2 as answered on their help page here:
https://help.heroku.com/JAOCNZ25/does-heroku-have-plans-to-support-http-2

> HTTP/2 is not currently supported on Heroku although this may change in future. You can find out about our currently supported HTTP protocols here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#http-versions-supported

In the linked page is this text:

> Three main versions of HTTP are used in the wild: HTTP/0.9, HTTP/1.0, and HTTP/1.1.
>
> The Heroku router only supports HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 clients. HTTP/0.9 and earlier are no longer supported. SPDY and HTTP/2 are not supported at this point.

Additionally heroku's open source reverse-proxying module also explicitly states that HTTP/2 is not supported:
https://github.com/heroku/vegur#protocol-details

> The vegur proxy only supports HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 clients. HTTP/0.9 and earlier are no longer supported. SPDY and HTTP/2.0 are not supported at this point.

You can tell the vegur is being used by doing a simple `curl -vv` to your app and nothing the `Via: 1.1 vegur` line in the response.

Comment: Thanks! About region I checked and they not ready to South America.